# THREE.js partial sphere geometry gives two segments where one segment expected

Tags: three.js, geometry

I am experimenting with making partial sphere geometries using the extended options of the THREE.SphereGeometry constructor e.g.

```
    // material
    var dish_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        color: 0x00ffff, 
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        ambient: 0x00ffff,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );

    var segment_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
        color: 0xffff00, 
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        ambient: 0x00ffff,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
    } );    

    // geometries
    var dish_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius=5, widthSegments=16, heightSegments=16, 
phiStart=0, phiLength=Math.PI*2, 
thetaStart=Math.PI, thetaLength=Math.PI/4);

    var segment_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius=5, widthSegments=16, heightSegments=16, 
phiStart=0, phiLength=Math.PI/4, 
thetaStart=0, thetaLength=Math.PI*2);

    // meshes
    dish = new THREE.Mesh( dish_geometry, dish_material );
    scene.add( dish );

    segment = new THREE.Mesh( segment_geometry, segment_material );
    scene.add( segment );
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q24cepa/3/) using the above code.

The "dish" object (blue) looks as expected.

But the "segment" object (yellow) has two segments where I would have expected just one.

**My Question**

Is this "double segment" the intended geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified thetaLength=Math.PI*2 which will result in a full circle. If that circle is rotated you will get the geometry you described.

I think you will want to write thetaLength=Math.PI instead.

Comment: Ah thanks, thetaLength=Math.PI is what I needed.  Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q24cepa/4/) .